# Text spilling out of container in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I'm currently creating a website and I noticed when using Internet Explorer 9 and below the text is spilling out of the page. Don't suppose if anyone knows of a fix and is it a common issue or just something wrong in my stylesheet? Here is a screenshot of the issue. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCGe2.png

Comment: Try posting the problem code in a minimal example in here (external links tend to disappear after a while and make it all impossible to comprehend)

Comment: Any code would be helpful.